# custom background uitableview with more than 1 section (IPHONE)

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

I need to set an image to my UITableViewController; if i have just one section on the tableview it works fine with:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.jpeg"]];
```

but if there are 2 section the image comes duplicate for each section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a pattern image.  Use the tableView's `backgroundView` property:

```
UIImageView * background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.jpeg"]];
[[self tableView] setBackgroundView:background];
[background release];
```