# iOS - UITableView Non-Static background image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I've read a lot of solutions to add a background image to a UITableView where the image will be static and the cells will scroll above it. 
However, I have yet to find a solution to setting an image that will scroll with the table.
When I execute the following code parts of the background image are propogated up into the background image of each cell.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper.png"]];
```

Can somebody please tell me if there is a way to do what I want in iOS 5?
Cheers
Brian

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283281/custom-background-uitableview-with-more-than-1-section-iphone)

Comment: Check out the 2011 WWDC videos (developer/Apple.com/videos). I think there's one on table views. If I remember correctly, it address this question or something close.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subclass UIView and implement a custom drawRect: method, and tile your image there using UIImage drawing methods (or even the Core Graphics ones).